# One of the Hyper-v components not running proxmox

Tags: proxmox

I'm running a Windows Server 2019 as a virtual machine on proxmox. Cant start docker desktop on this vm and getting this error:

"Failed to start the virtual machine 'DockerDesktopVM' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running."

Hyper-V settins are enabled on Server , KVM hardware virtualization is enabled on proxmox, what am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, PVE does not expose hardware-assisted virtualization extensions to VMs. Performance of hypervisor within VM will be degraded.

Enable nested support

1. Login to PVE terminal or via SSH or web gui -> Shell
2. To check if nested virtualization is enabled, bring up terminal/SSH/Shell, execute following command

`cat /sys/module/kvm_intel/parameters/nested`

> If it returns “N”, that means it’s disabled

To enable

```
# Intel
echo "options kvm-intel nested=Y" > /etc/modprobe.d/kvm-intel.conf
# AMD
echo "options kvm-amd nested=1" > /etc/modprobe.d/kvm-amd.conf
```

Then

```
# Intel
modprobe -r kvm_intel
modprobe kvm_intel
# AMD
modprobe -r kvm_amd
modprobe kvm_amd
```

> If error returns, just reboot the PVE host

Check again

```
# Intel
cat /sys/module/kvm_intel/parameters/nested
# AMD
cat /sys/module/kvm_amd/parameters/nested
```

We should get “Y” which means nested virtualization is enabled

To enable nested virtualization for guest VMs

Intel CPU:

- Set the CPU type for VMs to “host”

AMD CPU:

- Set the CPU type for VMs to “host”
- Add following flags to the configuration file

```
args: -cpu host,+svm
```

We can use following command to check/verify hardware virtualization support is enabled or not on Linux OSs

```
egrep '(vmx|svm)' --color=always /proc/cpuinfo
```

Official source Nested Virtualization – Proxmox VE:
https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Nested_Virtualization